# Access is not a valid path

Tags: ms-access

The code below is when a staff takes customers orders via the system and the system states "order sent".

The VB.NET works perfectly, it's just that the data from VB should automatically go to my Access Database. The problem below are codes lines 11/12 where I enter my database file and which will hold the data from VB.Net. It gives me

> "C:\user\public\stu-storage1\user-area\4\oo423\My
>   Documents\Database511.accdb(Access 2007 - 2013 file format) -Access'
>   is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled
>   correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file
>   resides".

```
MessageBox.Show("Order sent")

    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\user\public\\stu-storage1\user-area\4\oo423\My Documents\Database511.accdb(Access 2007 - 2013 file format) -Access"
    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    MyConnection = New OleDbConnection
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Database511", MyConnection)
    da.Fill(ds, "Database511.accdb")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
```

Comment: The name of my database is Database511.accdb.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is perfectly clear. So change this line to:

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\users\public\stu-storage1\user-area\4\oo423\My Documents\Database511.accdb"
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But I keep getting this error message "C:\user\public\stu-storage1\user-area\4\oo423\My Documents\Database511.accdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides".

Comment: Don't you think it should be `C:\users\...` - see edited answer.

Comment: It is actually, was a typo. Am still getting the same error.

Comment: Except for the space leading _Data Source=_ I'm out of ideas.